# Keep orignial column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to know why column names change in `R`. I have a data frame `df` looking like

```
            2        1         2        2        2         2         2
1 PARK7 10.306062 9.896181  9.735218 9.954633 7.860466 10.258330 10.335949
2  GUK1  8.065012 8.749869  7.446256 7.714932 9.031494  7.472488  8.867279
3  RPS7  8.850187 9.618386  7.877744 9.139807 9.671187  9.627716  9.775775
4   MSN  9.358871 9.906740  9.636625 9.013183 9.229059  9.376560  9.327103
5 CSRP1 10.751795 9.939579 10.611670 9.225930 9.753050 10.634176 10.346735
```

And I try to change first column into row names by

```
names <- df[,-1]
rownames(names) <- df[,1]
```

But it changes the column names and the output comes like

```
           2        1       2.1      2.2      2.3       2.4       2.5
 PARK7 10.306062 9.896181  9.735218 9.954633 7.860466 10.258330 10.335949
  GUK1  8.065012 8.749869  7.446256 7.714932 9.031494  7.472488  8.867279
  RPS7  8.850187 9.618386  7.877744 9.139807 9.671187  9.627716  9.775775
   MSN  9.358871 9.906740  9.636625 9.013183 9.229059  9.376560  9.327103
 CSRP1 10.751795 9.939579 10.611670 9.225930 9.753050 10.634176 10.346735
```

Why the column name change, and how can I retain the original column names.

Comment: How did you created this dataset?

Comment: Its a brain cancer `dataset` that comes with `MetaQC` R package

Comment: I checked the dataset `brain`.  It is a `list` of `matric`es.

Comment: So we can have duplicate `column names` with matrix??

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: Thanks, one last concern, the data you showed below does not give any problem when I use it from package. But I downloaded the data in that list and uploaded again to check working of other data formates. So how should i upload the data to overcome this problem (`read.csv`, `read.table`, etc.)

Comment: That is a different thing.  You are reading it as a data.frame then.  But, if you are using `read.csv/read.table` etc by default it will add an `X` to have it as a character column name instead of number only.  To avoid that, use `check.names = FALSE`.  However, it is better to have no duplicate column names and number only names.

Answer (score 0):

In `data.frame`s by default duplicate column names are not preferred as it can lead to confusion in calling the columns by name.  It uses `make.unique` to change the column names to unique.  To illustrate the point

```
v1 <- make.unique(as.character(c(2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)))
v1
#[1] "2"   "1"   "2.1" "2.2" "2.3" "2.4" "2.5"
```

We can use `sub` to remove the substring

```
sub("\\..*", "", v1)
#[1] "2" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2"
```

---

Using the dataset from "MetaQC"

```
 library(MetaQC)
 data(brain)
 df <- brain[[1]][1:4, 1:4]
 is.matrix(df)
 #[1] TRUE

 rownames(df) <- NULL
 df
 #           2        1        2        2
 #[1,] 10.306062 9.896181 9.735218 9.954633
 #[2,]  8.065012 8.749869 7.446256 7.714932
 #[3,]  8.850187 9.618386 7.877744 9.139807
 #[4,]  9.358871 9.906740 9.636625 9.013183
```

Comment: Thanks, do you mean it is not a `dataframe` before

Comment: @KhawajaOwaiseHussain  It is possible to create `data.frame` with duplicate column names, but when we do this assignment with `rownames`, it calls the make.unique i.e. `as.data.frame(cbind(`1`= 1:5, `2`= 6:10, `1` = 11:15))`

Comment: How can i avoid the problem while adding rownames

Comment: @KhawajaOwaiseHussain  Your `names` is problematic.  `names <- df[,-1]` as it is selecting all the columns except the first one.  Did you meant `names <- df[,1]`.  In addition, it is better to have the dataset with unique column names rather than duplicates.

Comment: @KhawajaOwaiseHussain  I tried to reproduce your problem, but it didn't change for me. i.e. `df <- as.data.frame(cbind("1"= 1:5, "2"= 6:10, "1" = 11:15)); rownames(df) <- df[,1]; names(df)#
[1] "1" "2" "1"`

Comment: Its changing for me, even on creating `list` also.

Comment: @KhawajaOwaiseHussain  So, it must be calling the `make.unique`.  If you wnt to change it back use the `sub` in my updated post